How to extract path details from sharing link?
I have a link like https://Site.com/:f:/g/EZbyBEYvwBGolyOlTcIFCsBMHvkZVhxKmH41o4D0egmg and need to get this path in some readable form like https://Site.com/Shared%20Documents/Folders through external system (Power Automate), is it possible? I need to put a file there, but related action wants decoded Folder Path

I think that is a sharing link and unique for that document. I don't think you can extract the path from that link.
